# On ASP page, setting maxlength for the textbox field based on textbox size

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have a file "sample.asp" page.

```
<input type="text" name="ticker" id="ticker" value="<%=strTicker%>" size="107" />
```

On this text field, I have set size to `107`.

How can I define the `MaxLength` based on `size` of textbox field?

First preference to English characters 
Second is for other language characters

Thanks in advance for the solution.

Comment: I don't understand you question. What's wrong with maxlength="somesize"

Comment: @Ash: the scenario is to not go beyond the text size. Since what ever text, user enters that should be visible in text box itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ticker_element = document.getElementById("ticker");
ticker_element.setAttribute("maxlength", ticker_element.size
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks george for the info. I should not assign the size value directly to maxlength. I'm expecting to do some calculation, where we can find the maxlength based on the size of textbox. It should be some KeyUp & KeyDown function where we can do some kind of calculation for maxlength.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Do you want to set the maxlength *after* the user has entered text into the field? If so, that would defeat the purpose of maxlength.

Comment: I will take some examples to explain: if I set `maxlength=90` & `size=90` then if user enters letter 'W' & 'i' 90 characters but visible characters on textbox is only 60 chars for 'W' & 'i' appears very less.. for 'W', to see remaining 30 chars.. we need to scroll. If user enters combination of chars then sometimes charas will flow beyond the textbox visible area and combination can fit exactly.. To overcome this, I should write some javascript on ASP page, while entering letters (on Keypress & Keyrelease) then i should calculate the maxlength based on the size of textbox...

Comment: The size attribute controls the "visible characters" of the text box. If you set size=90, 90 characters will be visible. Therefore, if you want to limit the number of characters to the visible size of the textbox, you should set maxlength equal to size, as I indicated above.

Comment: I tried this way some hours back, but text flow inside the textbox. There should be some way to set the maxlength. I'm not getting proper ideas to resolve this issue.. Let me know if any thoughts where we can solve this.. thanks george

Comment: Keep in mind that the size attribute sets the size of the input in characters. If you are using some other method to change the size of the input (such as with CSS), you may be overriding the size attribute. Can you check if this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in ASP:

```
<%
Dim size
size = "107"
%>
<input type="text" name="ticker" id="ticker" value="<%=strTicker%>" size="<%=size%>" maxlength="<%=size%>" />
```